# pandas grooup by according to group of days of the week

Tags: pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby, weekday

I have this dataframe:

```
2018-01-01 01:00:00   3.479
2018-01-01 02:00:00   3.477
2018-01-01 03:00:00   3.475
2018-01-01 04:00:00   3.472
2018-01-01 05:00:00   3.470
                    ...
2018-01-07 20:00:00   3.149
2018-01-07 21:00:00   3.147
2018-01-07 22:00:00   3.145
2018-01-07 23:00:00   3.143
2018-01-08 00:00:00   3.141
```

I know that I could compute the daily mean as:

```
dfn = dfr.resample('D').mean()
```

However, I would like to do something little different. I would like to sum o compute the mean of the first three days of each week as well as the last fourth days of the week. A little note: I do not know when my data start.

I try to make myself clear. Here the example:
[image]

In the figure you can see that I have a value for each day (my real dataframe has hourly values). I would like to compute the mean for each set (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday) (Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday) for each day. In this example I have only two days so I would expect from my algorithm to have four value.

I have the feeling that I could apply something related to groupby but I am not able to set-up the solution.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you expect four values if you had two weeks? Also what do you mean by not knowing the start of the week?

Comment: What do you mean by: 
>  I do not know if my week start on Monday or on Wednesday.
Could you add an example?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

A similar data frame:

```
rng = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2018-01-21')
rnd_values = np.random.rand(len(rng))+3

df = pd.DataFrame({'time':rng.to_list(),'value':rnd_values})
```

Identify the two different spans:

```
df['span'] = \
    np.where((df['time'].dt.day_of_week == 0) | (df['time'].dt.day_of_week >= 4), 'Th-Sn', 'Mn-Wd')
```

Give a prefix identifier to each span (I used week number.  Span start date would be another option):

```
df['wkno'] = df['time'].dt.isocalendar().week.shift(fill_value=0)
```

Get the mean of each span:

```
df.groupby(['wkno','span']).mean()

               value
wkno span           
0    Th-Sn  3.916292
1    Mn-Wd  3.597244
     Th-Sn  3.794555
2    Mn-Wd  3.295676
     Th-Sn  3.478448
3    Mn-Wd  3.610433
     Th-Sn  3.455591
```

Comment: It is wonderful. However, I work with DateIndex. Consequently, I use "dfr.index.dayofweek". I hope that this option is correct. The algorithm seems not working properly. Indeed my first day is  the 2018-01-01 01:00:00 a Monday but I get dfr['span'] =  Th-Sn